# What is the best (in terms of effectively building understanding) direction from which to approach manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Thedore Frankel's book [The Geometry of Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602602) presents Manifolds right away in Chapter 1 in the following manner:

1. Introduce the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^N$ only as "the most important manifold".
2. A subset $M = M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+r}$ is said to be  an $n$-dimensional  submanifold  of 
   $\mathbb{R}^{n+r}$
   , 
   if  locally $M$ can  be described by giving $r$  of  the coordinates differentiably  in  terms  of 
   the  $n$  remaining ones. This means that  given  $p \in M$,  a  neighborhood of $p$  on  $M$can 
   be described in  some coordinate  system $(x, y)  =  (x^1,  . . .  , x^n
   , 
   y^1
   , 
   . .
   . 
   , y^r
   )$  of 
   $\mathbb{R}^{n+r}$ 
   by 
   $r$  differentiable functions 
   $y^{\alpha} = f^{\alpha}(x^1,...,x^n)$,  where $\alpha  =  1,  . ..  r$

However, other books generally present manifolds much later, and in terms of the vocabulary of topology.

I find that Frankel's presentation doesn't provide me with any useful intuition, and it has a lot of rigorous loopholes (e.g. what is "differentiable"? differentiable where?, etc.).

Could you help either make his presentation more precise, or would you suggest that I take the route of other textbooks, and take the "long way around" to manifolds after doing a fair bit of topology/differential geometry before tackling manifolds?

Comment: I would say that thinking of manifolds as a subset of $R^N$ is a lot more intuitive than the definition of abstract manifolds as a topological space with charts. In fact, Whitney Embedding theorem says that all finite dimensional manifolds can be embedded into $R^N$ for sufficiently large $N$, so you aren't losing too much. In fact, even pure mathematicians like John Milnor uses this definition (subset of $R^N$) in many of his books.

Comment: @Braindead Where are these functions differentiable (assuming the usual definition of differentiable)? On $M$?

Comment: $f^\alpha$ is a differentiable function on an open subset of $R^n$.

Comment: Note that $f^\alpha$ only takes in $n$-variables, so it can't possibly be a function on $M$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a follow up on my comment above. This is by no means a complete answer and it should not really be treated as one.

The best way to gain intuition is to look at examples.

Let's look at the sphere, $S^2 = \{ (a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1\}$.

In this case, $M = S^2$. $n = 2$, and $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^{2+1}$.

Locally, $M$ can be described as a graph of a function. For instance, consider the subset of $M$ where $c>0$. Here, we can write $c = \sqrt{1-a^2 - b^2}$. Using the notation of Frankel's book:

$(x,y) = (x^1, x^2, y^1) = (a,b,c)$, with $c = y^1 = f^1(x^1,x^2) = f^1(a,b) = \sqrt{1-a^2 - b^2}$

Note that $f^1(a,b) = \sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}$ is a differentiable function on an open subset of $R^2$. (Namely, the set $\{(a,b)\in R^2: a^2+b^2 < 1\}$, which is precisely the set that maps into $c>0$ on $M$ under this map.)

The differentiability here is in the usual sense of being differentiable as a function of two variables.

What I have described here is one of the coordinate charts on $M$. See if you can find the rest of the coordinate chart. Note that it is very important that the patches cover all of $M$. (My chart only covers the points on $M$ with $c>0$. But what about the other points?)

> EDIT: I just realized that this example is the second example in the said book, on pgs. 4-5.

Comment: I even used the same exact coordinate chart! How spooky.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer despite your statement that it should not be treated as a complete answer, because it is very helpful in setting me off on the right path. It does much more than simply convince me that I should spend some more time digesting this approach rather than quickly throwing up my hands, but that is one the best characteristics of your answer. Thanks.